# Clarification on SSL Handshake

Tags: java, ssl, https

This question is a follow-up of [SSL handshake failure when importing certificates from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642829/ssl-handshake-failure-when-importing-certificates-from-file)

In that link, SSL handshake failed when using third-party certificates.

I have doubt regarding that.

Whether the client encodes every message using Server's public key once the server has issued its certificate containing public key to the client ?

Comment: Not really a follow-up: just a general question about SSL, often asked, and often answered wrongly.

Comment: @EJP, and there's even a [question with fairly good answers on Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work) about that, which just also happens to be the top result of a Google search for "How does SSL work?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whether the client encodes every message using Server's public key once the server has issued its certificate containing public key to the client ?

No. SSL uses symmetric encryption using a negotiated session key. Not public-key encryption.